# How can I use a file in a Windows Store App Testproject?

Tags: io, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, file-access

I am getting my feet wet with making a Windows Store application. It will convert a text based file to a class. For this the application needs file access. That I can accomplish. but I created a Windows Store App Testproject with a sample text based file that I want the app to parse. I tried to add access to the Documents folder for the test project, but I seem unable to get file access. How is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, but It's really recommended you don't. First I will tell you how to do it:-

Go to the package.appxmanifest, and capabilities. Then tick "Documents Library"

You can then do the following:-

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
StorageFile file = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("filename.txt");
```

Note that it will throw an IOException if the file doesn't exist - there is no way to check beforehand :-(

However, this will not get accepted into the store. The recommended approach is to use a file picker. The code is pretty simple, and I have shown it below:-

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker(); 
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail; 
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary; 
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");  
StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

This will get into the store fine.

Comment: Thanks, for the test project enabling the DocumentsLibrary capability is acceptable. However, when I paste the FileOpenPicker code in a Button_Click eventhandler I can see that the code stops at the await for ever because curiously no kind of file dialog is shown.

Comment: strange, I have added a button to a project, and added the exact code above to the event - the only thing I had to do was put async before the void part of the method and it worked a treat. I'm happy to drop the project on skydrive if you want, but it's very straightforward.

Comment: I've answered your other question - this wasn't working because of another issue in your code. Remember you only need to enable document library if you are using the first bit of code, the second bit does not need that permission.